# git - How to checkout all changed files between two commits

Tags: git, merge, commit, git-branch, git-checkout

I have a branch A and a branch B. Branch B is three commits ahead of A.

I can use `git diff` to list the changed files between A and B.

But my question is: How can I checkout all those changed files between A and B while I am on A, then commit them altogether into A as one commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `B` is strictly ahead of `A` (and not behind it), then you can simply run "merge --squash":

```
git merge --squash B
git commit
```

Comment: Thanks @max630, I just need to replace A with B in your answer, as I am on A and want to checkout/merge files from B

Comment: Sure, it it should have been B. My mistake. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

Simply pull the `B` branch into `A` then, merge last three commits as one.

```
$ git checkout A
$ git pull origin B
$ git log
# Now top 3 commits are B's commit

# now back to 3 commits but exists all changes of that 3 commits (soft reset)
$ git log
# copy the last commit-hash of A (before pulled)                    

$ git reset --soft <commit-hash>

# now do one commit with all changes
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'add last 3 commits of B as one in A'
$ git push origin HEAD         # push the changes to remote
```

Answer (score 0):

Rebase the commits onto A and then squash them togeter to one commit with

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the commits from the B through rebase

> > git rebase B

Now squash three commits in to one

> > git rebase -i HEAD~3